# How to start a service from Handler

Tags: android, android-service

I have a basic question on starting a Service.

I have a Service which starts a Thread for parsing a file; once this is done the same is communicated back by sending a Message.

Now, after receiving this Message in a Handler of the Service, I want to start another Service.

Since Handler doesn't have the Context, how do I start another Service?

One option is to send a local broadcast and receive the same and start Service, but is there any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

It'll be something like this

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainActivity);

    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.what = 0;
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}


Handler mHandler = new Handler()
{
 public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {

    if(msg.what==0) 
{
       StartService(new Intent(Myservice.this,    secondservice.class));
            finish();
 }          

    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a custom handler who need a Context :

```
public class CustomHandler extends Handler {
    Context mContext;

    public CustomHandler(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(msg.what == ID_STARTSERVICE) {
             Intent i = new Intent...
             mContext.startService(i);
        }
    }
}
```

But make sure you pass the ApplicationContext ( new CustomHandler(getApplicationContext() ) ) and not an Activity context.

Answer (score 0):

You can start service from Handler without using reference to Context this way:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
serviceIntent.setAction("your.package.UpdaterServieName");
startService(serviceIntent);
```

I hope I understood your question and this reply could be useful to you.

Sorry for my english.